# Python switch being buggy

Tags: python

```
    while 2 > 1:

    if keyboard.is_pressed(hotkey) and start == 0:
        print("On")
        start = 1
        time.sleep(0.2)

    if keyboard.is_pressed(hotkey) and start == 1:
        print("Off")
        start = 0
        time.sleep(0.2)

    if start == 1 and Y == 0:
        mouse.click(button="left")
        Y = 1
        time.sleep(1)
        Y = 0
        continue
```

I'm trying to make a switch that makes the program click until the user clicks a button to turn the switch off. But the switch takes around 15 tries to recognize that the program has been turned off. Just curious what I've done wrong.

Comment: Could you post the rest of your program please? Trying to run this shows `NameError: name 'hotkey' is not defined`.

Comment: What I can see is that in `if keyboard.is_pressed(hotkey) and start = 0:` you set `start`to `1` then you sleep for 0.2 seconds. If you release the key in less than 200 milliseconds the next if statement won't trigger. But there's more: I don't see how you ever leave the loop. BTW, please fix the indentation of your code example. We can only guess what is part of the loop and what not.

Comment: You should really improve the wording of your question. "until the user clicks a button" - that's actually "until the user presses a hotkey" from what I see in the code. "to turn the switch off" - the switch is called `start`, which is not a good name. A better name would be `is_active`. And from what I see, that could be a boolean, because it is a switch. "the program has been turned off" should be "the switch is turned off".

Answer (score 0):

`is_pressed()` will only return `True` if the key is pressed in the moment that you query for it. If the key is pressed during one of the `sleep()` methods, nothing will happen.

Use the [`on_press_key()`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardon_press_keykey-callback-suppressfalse) or [`add_hotkey()`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardadd_hotkeyhotkey-callback-args-suppressfalse-timeout1-trigger_on_releasefalse) event instead.

Look at this demo to get the concept:

```py
import keyboard
import time

status = True
def onoff(eventtype):
    global status
    status=not status # Toggle
    print("On" if status else "Off")

keyboard.on_press_key("space", onoff)
time.sleep(10)
```

Note that it still handles your key presses during the sleep phase.

Comment: Thanks, I know i didn't lay the question out well but this helped a lot.